# ZF2: pthreads - Passing PDO

Tags: php, multithreading, pdo

This is my first time using pthreads.

I have a Controller that runs multiple threads. Each thread will do lots of processing, and it will wait for a file to download. Later, it will save to a database.

Previously in the controller I used to get an instance of the database connection using:

```
public function getAppTable() {
        if (!$this->appTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->appTable = $sm->get('AppTable');
        }
        return $this->appTable;
    }
```

However if I try to do this in my `Thread` extending class, I'll get `getServiceLocator` is not defined due to the fact that the class does not extend Controller. I cannot pass `$this->appTable` to the Thread as PDO cannot be serialized or unserialized.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I doubt it's possible. You could try extending `PDO` from `Threaded` by using [`Threaded::from()`](http://php.net/threaded.extend), but I guess it will break. Your best bet is probably establishing one connection per thread.

Comment: And maybe use [persistent connections](http://php.net/pdo.constants#pdo.constants.attr-persistent) to keep overhead low.